# Update priorities on mongo based on host name using JS

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to adjust priorities of the nodes based on hostname instead of sequence.

Using sequence -

```
cfg=rs.conf()
cfg.members[0].priority=100 
cfg.members[1].priority=10
cfg.members[2].priority=10
cfg.members[3].priority=0
cfg.members[4].priority=0
rs.reconfig(cfg)
```

What I would need is something like,

```
cfg=rs.conf()
cfg.members[where name like 'abc'].priority=100 
cfg.members[where name like 'pqr'].priority=10
cfg.members[where name like 'xyz'].priority=10
cfg.members[where name like '10.12.13.14'].priority=0
cfg.members[where name like '10.12.13.14'].priority=0
rs.reconfig(cfg)
```

Updating bulk of replica sets of different clusters would be difficulty with sequences.

Sequence of hostnames are not in ordered.
So if I need to update specific host with highest priority during maintenance I cannot rely on sequence.
May be using java script is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a Javascript like this:

```
cfg = rs.conf()
cfg.members.forEach(function(member) {
   if (member.host.includes("abc"))
      member.priority = 100
   else if (/xyz/.test(member.host))
      member.priority = 10
   else if (member.host == '10.12.13.14')
      member.priority = 0;
})
rs.reconfig(cfg)
```

Comment: another similar question if I've to get something like analogous to statement in SQL from rs.status output in mongoDB - `select health from rs.status where hostname like 'abc:123'` what would be the query in mongoDB ?

Comment: Wernfried Domscheit I've posted a new question - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/295799/mongodb-query-or-js-to-print-health-state-of-a-replica-node