# mongodb query or JS to print health state of a replica node

Tags: mongodb

If I've to get something like analogous to SQL statement from rs.status output to print specific value of an attribute in mongoDB -

Something like print health of specific node of a replica set from rs.status.

`select health from rs.status where hostname like 'abc:123'`

or something to print lagtime of a specific secondary replica node with respect to Primary node using :

`print lagtime from rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo() where hostname like 'abc:123'`

what would be the simple query or JS to run against a replica set connection string ?

Comment: Simply `rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo()`

Comment: but instead of printing everything with command `rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo()`. I would like to capture only specific key value like for health either 1 or 0 and assign that value to a variable in Linux shell. Is there any simplest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one-liner would be this one:

```
mongo "mongodb://username:password@localhost:27018/admin?authSource=admin" --quiet --norc --eval "rs.status().members.filter( x => x.name == db.hello().me ).shift().health"
```

Function `db.hello().me` returns the server+port you are currently connected to. Replace this expression if you like to query other server in this replica set.

Comment: Getting an error : `db.hello()
2021-07-20T04:49:24.093+0000 E QUERY    [js] TypeError: db.hello is not a function :`

Comment: db.hello() New in version 5.0: (and 4.4.2, 4.2.10, 4.0.21, and 3.6.21). As per - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.hello/

Comment: If you use an older mongoDB version try `db.hostInfo().system.hostname`

Comment: `db.hostInfo().system.hostname` works for me.